# Setting up Sublime Text up for Java and getting "bash: javac: command not found"

Tags: java, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am having trouble in setting up Sublime Text for Java programming.
When using the JavaC Build System, I am getting an error like this in the terminal:

```
bash: javac: command not found
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: javac “/home/vinays/Documents/HelloWorld.java”]
[dir: /home/vinays/Documents]
[path: /app/utils/bin:/app/sublime_merge/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin]
```

Then I had made myself a new build system like this:

```
}
 shell_cmd”: “java $file_name”,
“working_dir”: “${project_path:${folder}}”,
“path”: “/usr/bin/java”
}
```

Again it went wrong and shows:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: java HelloWorld.java]
[dir: /home/vinays/Documents]
[path: /app/utils/bin:/app/sublime_merge/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin]
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! It seems you have some issues with the `path` variable. Have you verified that you indeed have the commands present in your system? For that you can use `which` (i.e `which javac` will show you the path to where `javac` is installed), and if they're found in the system you can then add the directories they reside in to the `path` variable. For example, I'm pretty sure `bash` lives in `/bin`. Alternatively, you can (and probably should) also replace `javac` in the first `shell_cmd` with `/path/to/javac` to make absolutely sure.

Comment: Yes Sir I have verified the commands present in my system itself

Comment: kindly see the below answer......

Answer (score 2):

You've got a lot going wrong here, so lets take it in stages.

```
“bash: javac: command not found
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: javac “/home/vinays/Documents/HelloWorld.java”]
[dir: /home/vinays/Documents]
[path: /app/utils/bin:/app/sublime_merge/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin]”
```

This is an indication that the `sublime-build` file you tried to use (perhaps the one that ships with Sublime) tried to invoke `javac`, but it was not found anywhere on the path.

You also included the following in your answer:

```
~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

This is an indication that `java` is indeed available on the path; this is the command that you use to execute a Java program.

Since you have `java` but do not seem to have `javac`, my guess would be that you installed a JRE (Java Runtime Environment) and not a JDK (Java Development Kit). The first is meant for running Java applications only, while the second actually contains the tools and additional files needed to compile Java code.

So, your best bet is to verify that you actually have a JDK installed (perhaps by executing `which javac` to see what it says).

Further to that, you also provided this `sublime-build` file:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "java $file_name",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "path": "/usr/bin/java"
}
```

This is wrong for a couple of reasons. First, it's using `java` and not `javac`, so even if it did work and launch `java`, it would fail because `java` is for executing the compiled `class` file, not for compiling your code.

Secondly, `path` in a `sublime-build` file does not do what you think it does. Specifically, it tells Sublime to completely erase the contents of your `PATH` environment variable and then replace it with the content that you provide.

The `PATH` is for specifying the list of directories in which programs you want to run interactively live; here you've set it to the actual physical location of the `java` program itself (i.e. not a folder).

With that change in place, nothing can run any longer because the `PATH` is entirely invalidated. Hence your error here:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘bash’: No such file or directory
[Finished in 0.0s with exit code 127]
[shell_cmd: java HelloWorld.java]
[dir: /home/vinays/Documents]
[path: /app/utils/bin:/app/sublime_merge/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin]
```

This is the OS telling you that Sublime tried to run `bash` (the default shell), but it could not be found. It can't be found because the `path` was broken by your build (the `path:` listed is gathered for the debug diagnostic before the build starts, so it represents what the `path` was prior to the `sublime-build` file breaking it).

It's also worth noting that a command like `javac Something.java` just compiles the Java code, and then stops; this is almost certainly not what you want to do. You probably want to actually execute the code as well.

So, after you ensure that you actually have both `java` and `javac`, you should be able to get yourself up and running with a `sublime-build` file like this:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "javac \"$file_name\" && java \"$file_base_name\"",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

This will compile the single Java file and then, if it worked, execute it. Note that because your other build broke the `PATH`, you need to restart Sublime before any build will work.

This also doesn't help you work with any Java program that's more complicated than a single file. Java as a language does not lend itself well to ad-hoc compiling and running of files because the `class` files need to be in the appropriate package-specific location.

At some point you will need to upgrade yourself to using some Java-aware external build tool from Sublime, such as `Ant` or the like.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Sir I have verified my system commands i had got the following result:

```
~$ which java
/usr/bin/java
```

~$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac

More Over My path in sublime text is also Like This:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "java $file_name",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
    "path": "/usr/bin/java"
}
```